# How to run bar() inside foo() if bar() and foo() are mutually exclusive

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, pthreads

I have two functions, say foo() and bar(), I want them mutually exclusive, that is block the running of foo() entirely when bar() is running or block the running of bar() entirely when foo() is running for thread safety.

However, I may call bar() inside foo(), this is, when foo() calls bar() inside foo(), let bar() to run, but not any other threads call bar().

Is it possible? If yes, can you provide the general idea please?

Tried to use one or more mutex in C, it is easy to make two functions mutually exclusive, but then I cannot call bar() inside foo(), they will enter into a deadlock.

I can not just unlock the mutex right before calling bar() inside foo() because i cannot guarantee the next bar() running is the one called inside the foo().

I'm seeking a solution that foo will block bar, and bar will block foo if they run in the different threads. but when foo calling bar inside its body (same thread), let bar run.

Thanks

Comment: `However, I may call bar() inside foo(), this is, when foo() calls bar() inside foo(), let bar() to run, but not any other threads call bar().` Don't ever try to explain the code perhaps include sample code.

Comment: My idea is to use the thread ID as a base , and mutex that ID , So T1 calls Foo, sets the Thread ID, and continues,  T2 calls Bar, gets blocked (different Thread ID).  T1 calls Bar , can since same thread ID.  This is a very very very general idea.

Comment: Show code for us

Comment: @Gar If I understood your idea well the only way to access bar() is to call it from foo() not great :/ and what would happen if one thread goes into foo() the other in bar() and they both wan't to access the other function, you would have a deadlock here.

Comment: Not at all, if bar isn't called (nor foo) any of them can be called since the stored threadID is null , once one of them is called, the threadID will be filled, and stops any other thread from entering .

Comment: @Gar Ok didn't understand your idea well, now I get it. Seems it should work :)

Comment: I think you should reconsider what you're asking. For thread safety, you're actually interested in what data gets modified; you don't/shouldn't care about what functions run (except as they modify shared data). By flipping it around, it may make your task clearer. It seems likely that a recursive mutex will easily solve your problem, but again that requires careful consideration of what is actually being guarded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is move the main implementation of `bar()` and `foo()` to separate helper functions `bar_unlocked()` and `foo_unlocked()`, then implement `bar()` and `foo()` as:

```
type foo(args)
{
    type result;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&barfoo_lock);
    result = foo_unlocked(args);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&barfoo_lock);

    return result;
}

type bar(args)
{
    type result;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&barfoo_lock);
    result = bar_unlocked(args);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&barfoo_lock);

    return result;
}
```

You can safely call `bar_unlocked()` from within the implementation of `foo_unlocked()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is with a so-called "reentrant" or "recursive" mutex/lock object.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex

It works exactly the same as a regular lock except that a call to `lock()` from a thread that already has locked it will succeed, and a call to `unlock()` will *not* unlock the mutex until the thread has `unlock()`ed the lock as many times as it `lock()`ed the lock.

Recursive locks are a feature that appears in many different multi-threading libraries, but I don't know about the pthreads library, so maybe @caf 's answer will be a better choice for you.

Comment: Recursive mutexes can be created in pthreads by initialising the mutex with an mutexattr object on which the mutex type has been set to `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` with `pthread_mutexattr_settype()`.  It is generally simpler to analyse the behaviour of the program if you avoid relying on this sort of thing, though.